# Get all words starting with X and ending with Y

Tags: javascript, regex

I have got a textarea with `keyup=validate()`

I need a javascript function that gets all words starting with `@` and ending with a character that is not `A-Za-z0-9`

For example:

```
This is a text @user1 this is more text @user2. And this is even more @user3!
```

The function gives an array:

```
Array("@user1","@user2","@user3");
```

I am sure there must be a way to do this written on somewhere on the internet if I just google something but I have no idea what I have to look for.. I am very new with regular expresions.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Look like a job for regular expression to me

Comment: @Paul: "*I am very new with reg expresions.*" indeed.

Comment: Take a look here to understand regular expressions in javascript. [MDN Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Your description and example don't seem to match. You said to find words that _don't_ end with a letter or number. But `@user1` ends with a number.

Comment: @DavidThomas I am sorry I don't know what you mean with your comment. I am not English, and since I couldn't find a good website like this one in my language, I have to use this one. I am new with regular expressions, and I am new with English. And here I am, learning both. It would be easier for me to learn all this stuff if I were a USA resident and speak English, but no one can choose where they are going to be born. I don't think I deserve such a mean comment. Have a nice day.

Comment: The best web site for learning regular expressions is regular-expressions.info

Comment: @ice24 did you mean starting with @ and ending with number ?

Comment: @Barmar I said to get the word that contains letters and numbers. The space after the user1 is the special character that breaks the string.

Comment: Your language was confusing, because "words ending with Y" means that `Y` is part of the word. Like if you wanted to find all past tense words, you would look for words ending with "ed".

Comment: @Barmar That's right. My fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular expression you want is:

```
/@[a-z\d]+/ig
```

This matches `@` followed by a sequence of letters and numbers. The `i` modifier makes it case-insensitive, so you don't have to put `A-Z` in the character class, and `g` makes it find all the matches.

```
var str = "This is a text @user1 this is more text @user2. And this is even more @user3!";
var matches = str.match(/@[a-z\d]+/ig);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Nice answer, could even shorten it down to `/@\w+/g` where w is a shorthand to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`. No **i** caseless modifier necessary then.

Comment: Could do that if he allowed `_` in his usernames, but he doesn't. I asked him in a comment to Ani's answer.

Answer (score 1):

**JS**

```
var str = "This is a text @user1 this is more text @user2. And this is even more @user3!",
var textArr = str.split(" ");
for(var i = 0; i < textArr.length; i++) {
        var test = textArr[i];
        matches = test.match(/^@.*.[A-Za-z0-9]$/);
        console.log(matches);
};
```

**Explanation:** 
You should also read about the regex(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) and match(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) to get an idea how it works.
Basically, applying `^@` means starting the regex look for `@`. `$` means ending with. and `.*` any character in between.

**To Test:**  http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Comment: Upvoted yours, since any edit to my own suggestion would, basically, have turned it into the same regular expression you suggest here. Though I would suggest you *explain* the regular expression, and perhaps link to the relevant documentation of thhe `match()` method and such.

Comment: No problem. I thought I was wrong. Read the question three times after your answer :P

Comment: Yeah, as did I, after your comment... ;) I think the problem I had was the phrasing and the posted result (I thought, for some reason, that was the *desired* output rather than the *actual* output). Sigh...long day... :)

Comment: I have tried it on Firefox and the console says "null". What's wrong?

Comment: This regexp doesn't find words in the string. It tests whether the _entire_ string matches that regular expression, since `^` matches the start of the input, and `$` matches the end of the input.

Comment: You don't have a match :)

Comment: ice24 @barmar is correct. Looks like I misunderstood what you want. I am still not sure what you want though, baffled.

Comment: @Ani What i need is just to get the usernames from the string the user imputs. For example in twitter, or even stackoverflow, they detect the @ and they get the word just after to notify that user they got mentioned on a comment. I need to do that in javascript to highlight it when the user enters a username.

Comment: You don't allow `_` in your usernames?

Comment: You're still misunderstanding the question, because he worded it poorly. He doesn't mean words ending with `[^A-Za-z0-9]`, he means that that character set is the delimiter after the word.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies above, they've helped me - Where I've written this method that hopefully answers the question about having a start and end regex check.

In this example it looks for ##_ at the start and _## at the end

e.g. ##_ anyTokenYouNeedToFind _##.

Code:

```
const tokenSearchHelper = (inputText) => {

    let matches = inputText.match(/##_[a-zA-Z0-9_\d]+_##/ig);
    return matches;

}

const out = tokenSearchHelper("Hello ##_World_##");
console.log(out);
```